# Why angular-cli webpack in folder dist (-prod) has gzip files as well as not gzip files

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am interested in Angular-cli structure. When I build prod, (ng build -prod) I got folder dist where I found same files, just one of them is gzip, another is not.

Structure folder `/dist`:

[image]

Do I need gzip files or not? or maybe instead of gzip I do not need just JS files. Why do I have to hold two copies of the files?.

My folder gets more weight because of that. Could you explain to me how this works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ### Update
>
> Gzip generation has been removed the Angular CLI because it was confusing to many people, and now the CLI only outputs the files you actually use.
>
> For more information, check out the official `ng build` [documentation](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build).

The `gz` files exist so you can check the real size the `js` files will have when sent to the browser. Because you are almost definitely going to use GZIP on the server.

You can skip generating them by adding `--suppress-sizes true`.

That will remove most of them. There's a bug that makes it leave one `gz` still, which you can still workaround by adding `--vendor-chunk false`.

You can see more optimizations and get the context from [my comment on this issue in the Angular CLI repository](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3717#issuecomment-268967438).